# Calendar offset issue

Tags: java, date, calendar

I need to get the month and day of today's date and offset dates. This is how I do it:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 0);
Date today = calendar.getTime();

System.out.println(today);
```

Output:

```
Wed Aug 27 15:07:35 CEST 2014
```

Two things, I need the month and the day to be numeric, like 8/27. I understand how to do that with today's date like so:

```
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
String a = String.valueOf(day);
String b = String.valueOf(month);
System.out.println(b +"/" + a);
```

My issue is that I might need to add an offset to that date, if I want tomorrows date for example. Is there a way to do that because converting Wed Aug 27.... to 8/27 would just be a pain. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String calAsString = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(calAsString);

    // Now for tomorrow's date:
    int offset = 1;
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, offset);
    calAsString = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(calAsString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use simple date format:

Something like:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
    Date today = calendar.getTime();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(today));
```

Comment: note: pattern is not the same as OP asked for, but I still think, it is nice example how to show how the formatting should be used...

Answer (score 0):

Use the Calendar to add a value to the day:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1)
```